# Не спеша - требуется ли обособление?

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

1) Затем он уселся перед столиком и не спеша начал наполнять бокал жидкостью из графина.
2) Пил он также не спеша, обдумывая прошедший день.
Зная, что "не спеша" не является деепричастием, делаю вывод, что обособлять его не следует. Но для уверенности  решила спросить у специалистов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*1) Затем он уселся перед столиком и **не спеша (= медленно)** начал наполнять бокал жидкостью из графина.
2) Пил он **также не спеша**, обдумывая прошедший день.*

***Не спеша*** может обособляться или не обособляться, это зависит от структуры предложения.

Деепричастие не обособляется, если **занимает в предложении позицию наречия,** тогда оно является обстоятельством образа действия. В этом случае оно **вписывается в структуру простого предложения,** его можно прочесть без обособления.

Но при перестройке предложения **обособление может стать возможным** (тогда деепричастие будет обозначать второе действие) например: *Он, **не спеша**, наполнял бокал и при это обдумывал прошедший день.*

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113

7. Обособление или необособление одиночного деепричастия может зависеть от места, занимаемого им по отношению к глаголу-сказуемому: одно и то же слово в начале или в середине предложения может обособляться, а в конце — нет.

Ужинали **не спеша**. (Марк.)
Через двор, **не спеша**, шагал приземистый, коротконогий, круглоголовый человек. (Марк.)

Comment: Спасибо вам за такое подробное объяснение

Answer (score 3):

Вы совершенно правы: это с виду деепричастие по форме на самом деле наречие и не обособляется.

Answer (score 1):

Тут хотелось бы поправить ваши мысли. "Не спеша" **может** являться деепричастием (как правило, оно входит только в ДО), однако в случае роли обстоятельства образа действия оно таковым не является и, соответственно, не обособляется. В обоих случаях обособление не требуется.

*P. S.:* смутило меня вот это предложение:

"Зная, что "не спеша" **не является деепричастием**, делаю вывод..."

Comment: Бот Ботович, спасибо за объяснение. Я имела в виду, что в данных предложениях, на мой взгляд, "не спеша" не выступает в роли деепричастия, а следовательно обособление не требуется. Но я не была уверена в своих суждениях - поэтому решила спросить. Значит,  оно здесь выступает в роли обстоятельства образа действия. Я вас правильно поняла?

Comment: Да, всё верно. Чтобы исключить недопонимание, я специально написал постскриптум

Comment: И вы сказали, что "не спеша" может выступать в роли деепричастия в составе деепричастного оборота. Если вам будет нетрудно, можете привести один такой пример для лучшего понимания?

Comment: Да, вот: "Он шёл, не спеша на поезд, потому что уже опоздал" Не очень хороший пример, но всё же. Вообще, как я сейчас понял, такие случаи крайне редки.

Comment: Да, теперь всё стало полностью ясно. Спасибо за всё.